# Qt5.0.0 ITK4.12 VTK 7.1.1 Visual Studio 2010 x64

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010, vtk, itk

I am trying to configure Qt5.0.0x64,  ITK4.12 and VTK 7.1.1 with Visual Studio 2010 x64. First, I installed Qt and I configured VTK successfully.  Unfortunately, I have got this error during the configuration of ITK :

```
    CMake Error at C:/Program Files/VTK/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/Modules/vtkGUISupportQt.cmake:16 (set): 
  Syntax error in cmake code at
    C:/Program Files/VTK/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/Modules/vtkGUISupportQt.cmake:16
```

when parsing string

```
  C:\Qt\qt-5.5.0-x64-\qt-5.5.0-x64\lib\cmake\Qt5
```

Invalid escape sequence \Q
Call Stack (most recent call first):

```
C:/Program Files/VTK/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/vtkModuleAPI.cmake:45 (include)
  C:/Program Files/VTK/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/vtkModuleAPI.cmake:15 (vtk_module_load)
  C:/Program Files/VTK/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/vtkModuleAPI.cmake:132 (_vtk_module_config_recurse)
  C:/Program Files/VTK/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/VTKConfig.cmake:89 (vtk_module_config)
  Modules/Bridge/VtkGlue/itk-module-init.cmake:9 (find_package)
  CMake/ITKModuleEnablement.cmake:318 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:337 (include)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify a path to Qt using forward slashes, not backslashes. Not `C:\Qt\qt-5.5.0-x64-\qt-5.5.0-x64\lib\cmake\Qt5`, but `C:/Qt/qt-5.5.0-x64-/qt-5.5.0-x64/lib/cmake/Qt5`